# TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given) in python 2 and python 3

Tags: python-2.7

I have added the subclass and self in super method arguments, still the 
        error remains. Any fix you can suggest? Moreover I have tried running the code on both python 2 and python 3, but the same issue prevails.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-4a9264e84ddd> in <module>()
49 model = Sequential()
50 model.add(LSTM(150, input_shape=(n_timesteps_in, n_features), 
return_sequences=True))
---> 51 model.add(AttentionDecoder(127, n_features))
52 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['acc'])
53 # train LSTM

 51 
 52         super(AttentionDecoder, self). __init__(units, output_dim)
 ---> 53         self.name = name
 54         self.return_sequences = True  # must return sequences
 55 

TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)





class AttentionDecoder(Recurrent):

def __init__(self, units, output_dim,
             activation='tanh',
             return_probabilities=False,
             name='AttentionDecoder',
             kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
             recurrent_initializer='orthogonal',
             bias_initializer='zeros',
             kernel_regularizer=None,
             bias_regularizer=None,
             activity_regularizer=None,
             kernel_constraint=None,
             bias_constraint=None,
             **kwargs):


    super(AttentionDecoder, self). __init__(units, output_dim)
    self.name = name
    self.return_sequences = True  # must return sequences
```